# Loop does not go back to the beginning, just reprinting first user's entry

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have decided to write first application without using any youtube guide, just coding everthing from scratch. I am happy with the results, but now my program just reprints first user entry/translation, and does not ask for new entry.

I have put almost all of my code into while loop, expecting that it will rerun the program and ask user for another input. I had some ideas using boolean/string arguments, but it still does not work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Have fun using my Pig Latin translator!");
        System.out.println("Those are the rules:");
        System.out.println("Words that start with a vowel (A, E, I, O, U) simply have \"ay\" appended to the end of the word. ");
        System.out.println("Words that start with a consonant have all consonant letters up to the first vowel moved to the end of the word, and \"-ay\" is appended. -('Y' is counted as a vowel in this context). ");
        System.out.println("Write a sentence or word to translate into Pig Latin!");
        String userInput = scanner.nextLine();

        // Loop to translate another word/sentence
        while (true) {
            // User input, checking is word/sentence contains only letters or " "
            while (!userInput.matches(("[a-zA-Z\\s]+"))) {
                System.out.println("Numbers and special characters are not allowed, please try again");
                userInput = scanner.nextLine();
            }
            // Splits sentence into words, then modifies the words based on first letter
            String[] split = userInput.split("\\s");

            for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                if (split[i].startsWith("a")) {
                    split[i] = split[i] + "ay ";
                    System.out.print(split[i].toLowerCase());
                } else if (split[i].startsWith("A")) {
                    split[i] = split[i] + "ay ";
                    System.out.print(split[i].toLowerCase());
                } else if (split[i].startsWith("e")) {
                    split[i] = split[i] + "ay ";
                    System.out.print(split[i].toLowerCase());
                } else if (split[i].startsWith("E")) {
                    split[i] = split[i] + "ay ";
                    System.out.print(split[i].toLowerCase());
                } else if (split[i].startsWith("i")) {
                    split[i] = split[i] + "ay ";
                    System.out.print(split[i].toLowerCase());
                } else if (split[i].startsWith("I")) {
                    split[i] = split[i] + "ay ";
                    System.out.print(split[i].toLowerCase());
                } else if (split[i].startsWith("o")) {
                    split[i] = split[i] + "ay ";
                    System.out.print(split[i].toLowerCase());
                } else if (split[i].startsWith("O")) {
                    split[i] = split[i] + "ay ";
                    System.out.print(split[i].toLowerCase());
                } else if (split[i].startsWith("u")) {
                    split[i] = split[i] + "ay ";
                    System.out.print(split[i].toLowerCase());
                } else if (split[i].startsWith("U")) {
                    split[i] = split[i] + "ay ";
                    System.out.print(split[i].toLowerCase());
                } else if (split[i].startsWith("y")) {
                    split[i] = split[i] + "ay ";
                    System.out.print(split[i].toLowerCase());
                } else if (split[i].startsWith("Y")) {
                    split[i] = split[i] + "ay ";
                    System.out.print(split[i].toLowerCase());
                } else {
                    split[i] = split[i].substring(1) + split[i].charAt(0) + "ay";
                    System.out.print(split[i].toLowerCase() + " ");
                }
            }
            // Asks if user want to translate another word/sentence and looping the application
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Do you want to translate another word/sentence?(y/n)");
            String translateAgain = scanner.nextLine();
            if (!translateAgain.equals("y")) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just move `String userInput = scanner.nextLine();` into the loop, too.

Comment: you only ever ask for new `userInput` inside your loop if the `userInput` is invalid (contains special characters). You also need to ask for new input if the user wants to translate again. You could easily do this by adding an `else` to your `if (!translateAgain.equals("y"))` block and inside that `else` ask for new user inout.

Comment: Also, you already use `toLowerCase`; can you think of a way how that might help reduce those 12 `if` statements? Even better, create a method `isVowel` and have just a single `if/else` in your loop!

Comment: it's because you read it first outside the loop. in the loop you only read it again, if it doesn't matches the regex, but if it matches once, and you don't alter the value of userInput, it'll always match

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone! I have used @tobias_k soultion as I have already spent too much time on this code, but knowledge for all the replies will be useful. I tried to shorten this code by creating an array storing all the vowels, but could not implement it successfully.

Comment: just a note: `split[i] = split[i].substring(1) + split[i].charAt(0) + "ay";` this is wrong from your rules `Words that start with a consonant have all consonant letters up to the first vowel moved to the end of the word, and \"-ay\" is appended. -('Y' is counted as a vowel in this context).` how do you know that every word will have a vowel in the index 1?  here is are some  examples  where the vowel is at index 2 `black, white , close, drain` and from your rules also, the Y is only counted as a vowel  in the second rule not the first

Answer (score 0):

> *"I have decided to write first application without using any youtube guide, just coding everthing from scratch. ..."*

Great work, it functions well.

As other users have mentioned, just move the following line to within the *while-loop*.

```java
String userInput = scanner.nextLine();
```

The reason I'm answering is because it's worth noting you could reduce the repeated *if-else* checks.

```java
char character;
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    character = split[i].charAt(0);
    switch (Character.toLowerCase(character)) {
        case 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y' -> { }
        default -> split[i] = split[i].substring(1) + split[i].charAt(0);
    }
    System.out.print(split[i].toLowerCase() + "ay ");
}
```

> *"... I had some ideas using boolean/string arguments, but it still does not work."*

Additionally, you can utilize a *boolean* to determine when to exit the loop, considering you're using *while (true)*.

And, for situations where the loop may only iterate once, you can utilize the *do-while* loop.

Also, you can check for an empty user input, as a way to determine when to exit the loop.

```java
boolean exit = false;
do {
    String userInput = scanner.nextLine();
    if (userInput.isEmpty()) exit = true;

} while (!exit);
```

Here is the complete code.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Have fun using my Pig Latin translator!");
    System.out.println("Those are the rules:");
    System.out.println("Words that start with a vowel (A, E, I, O, U) simply have \"ay\" appended to the end of the word. ");
    System.out.println("Words that start with a consonant have all consonant letters up to the first vowel moved to the end of the word, and \"-ay\" is appended. -('Y' is counted as a vowel in this context). ");
    System.out.println("Write a sentence or word to translate into Pig Latin!");

    // Loop to translate another word/sentence

    String userInput;
    String[] split;
    char character;
    boolean exit = false;
    do {
        userInput = scanner.nextLine();
        if (userInput.isEmpty()) exit = true;
        // User input, checking is word/sentence contains only letters or " "
        while (!userInput.matches(("[a-zA-Z\\s]+"))) {
            System.out.println("Numbers and special characters are not allowed, please try again");
            userInput = scanner.nextLine();
        }
        // Splits sentence into words, then modifies the words based on first letter
        split = userInput.split("\\s");

        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            character = split[i].charAt(0);
            switch (Character.toLowerCase(character)) {
                case 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y' -> { }
                default -> split[i] = split[i].substring(1) + split[i].charAt(0);
            }
            System.out.print(split[i].toLowerCase() + "ay ");
        }
        // Asks if user want to translate another word/sentence and looping the application
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Do you want to translate another word/sentence?(y/n)");
        if (!scanner.nextLine().equals("y")) exit = true;
    } while (!exit);
}
```

And, here is an example input and output.

```
Have fun using my Pig Latin translator!
Those are the rules:
Words that start with a vowel (A, E, I, O, U) simply have "ay" appended to the end of the word. 
Words that start with a consonant have all consonant letters up to the first vowel moved to the end of the word, and "-ay" is appended. -('Y' is counted as a vowel in this context). 
Write a sentence or word to translate into Pig Latin!
Write a sentence or word to translate into Pig Latin
riteway aay entencesay oray ordway otay ranslatetay intoay igpay atinlay  
Do you want to translate another word/sentence?(y/n)
```